# OpenRasta + OpenWrap?

Tags: build, openrasta, openwrap

I'm new to both OpenWrap and OpenRasta. Not really that interested in Openwrap other than that seems to be the way to get OpenRasta. Anyways i've installed openwrap and followed the following tutorial to the T:
[OpenWrap Tutorial](http://codebetter.com/sebastienlambla/2010/10/20/creating-a-new-project-with-openwrap/)

except of course i added OpenRasta-Core to my project:

```
O add-wrap openrasta-core
```

Everything completes without errors but OpenRasta is not added to my project:

Error   3   The type or namespace name 'OpenRasta' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Testing\OpenRasta\src\TestOpenRasta\Program.cs   7   7   TestOpenRasta

I'm not that familiar with the way that openwrap works and i'm not sure if its supposed to add a reference to your project or does some msbuild magic to dynamically added the references.

My Project is built using the .Net Framework 4.0 and it looks like the wrap directory only contains.Net Framework 3.5 version. Do i need to download the source and build manually?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call init-wrap which is not in the instructions, as far as I remember.

Comment: Actually it is. You call it twice. Once to create the project and once after you create your visual studio project under the src directory.